# Save .xml file from c# to my node.js webserver

Tags: c#, node.js, xml

My C# project saves some machine data in an XML file. I want to show this data in an HTML website in the network. I create the XML file like so:

```
StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
        "history.xml", 
        CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using (IRandomAccessStream writeStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    System.IO.Stream s = writeStream.AsStreamForWrite();
    XmlWriterSettings historyXMLwriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    historyXMLwriterSettings.Indent = true;
    historyXMLwriterSettings.IndentChars = " ";
    historyXMLwriterSettings.CloseOutput = true;
    historyXMLwriterSettings.Async = true;
    XmlWriter historyXMLwriter = XmlWriter.Create(s, historyXMLwriterSettings);
    XmlSerializer historyXMLserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Auftrag>));
    historyXMLserializer.Serialize(historyXMLwriter, auftragsliste);
    await historyXMLwriter.FlushAsync();
}
```

My problem is that I need the file `history.xml` in the second project "webserver" in the public folder. How can I create the file directly in this folder or copy it?

[image: Solution Explorer]

Comment: Use a MemoryStream if you do not need a file.

Comment: I need a file for my html site to show the data in a table

Comment: ??? How to you send a file to the html site?  Don't you send TEXT?